# My do while loop repeats forever when the user inputs a wrong character

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

My code for a main menu isn't functioning correctly. I cant find out why the do while loop repeats forever when the user inputs, a bool is set to true, and it works, but if the user inputs a wrong character, the loop continues forever. and displays "Invalid character. Please try again." and doesn't allow the user to input.

```
void mainmenu() {
bool wrong = false;
    system("cls");

    cout << "Hello! Welcome to the menu. ";
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "What would you like to do?\n";
    cout << "Options:\n";
    cout << "1. Password generator\n";
    int choice{ 0 };
    do {

        cin >> choice;


        if (choice == 1) {
            wrong = true;
            passgen();
            break;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid character. Please try again." << endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
        
    } while (!wrong);
```

}

Note- I didnt include the #include in this snippet of code, but the error is within the loop repetition.

Comment: What stops your `while` loop and do you update it if the user inputs something invalid?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a line of input from the user and parse it to see if it's valid, then write code that reads a line and parses it. Your current code only reads integers. So if there's input that isn't an integer, it will never read it and complain about it over and over.

A quick and dirty alternative is to read/ignore a line and throw it away after calling `cin.clear()`.

But I'm a big believer in writing code that does what you actually want to do. You want to read *whatever* the user inputs, whether it's an integer or not. So why does your code read an integer?